# How to pass external validation through model labels and error messages?

Tags: validation, internationalization, kohana, kohana-3

In Kohana 3.2, passing external validation on `Model_User` upon save, why won't the correct message show?

I have `user.php` in `application/messages/models` which reads and translates fine for the "internal" data, while `_external.php` resides in `application/messages/models/user`.

When _external data is invalid, the default error message from Kohana is shown, and thus not correctly translated or given the correct labels from `Model_User`.

Edit, with code:

```
// We have $_POST, register a new user
$user = ORM::factory('user');
/*
 *    Here a bunch of variables are set
 */
$extra = Validation::factory($_POST)->
        rule('email', 'email')-> // I run this check, because in my Model_User, email is filtered through Encrypt
        rule('name', 'not_empty'); // Same goes for name

try {
    $user->save($extra);
} catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
    $this->template->errors = $e->errors('models', true);
}
```

So, when `$extra` variables don't match the rule, I would like to get nice error messages from `application/messages/models/user/_external.php`, which looks like:

```
return array(
    'email' => array(
            'email'         => ':field must be a valid email address',
        ),
    'name' => array(
            'not_empty'     => ':field must not be empty',
        ),
);
```

Also, it would be nice if :field was fetched from Model_User "labels".

Comment: Can you post a code sample? What argument are you passing to the **errors()** function?

Comment: Added code above. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `_external.php` next to your `user.php` in the `messages/models` directory, not in the `messages/models/user` directory. I had the same problem, it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. Can't understand why I didn't try that. So that file goes for all external validation messages? What if different models use similar fields for validation?